# Cannot read properties of undefined on synchronous call to a rest api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, synchronous

I'm new to angular and I wasn't sure how to implement synchronous api calls. I implemented async/await from a few articles I read but it still seems like the variables are undefined meaning the console is printing before even initializing the variable. I need it to be synchronous because code further down the cycle function depends on accurate variables.

I'm making a small program where people can upload their own images and it will be displayed on the stage component. I'm saving the images as a blob on a mysql database and retrieving them one at a time depending on the names provided in my nameList array variable

What am I doing wrong when calling the api via synchronous call?

stage.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow" *ngIf="retrievedImage">
        <ng-container>
            <img [src]="retrievedImage"/>
            <h1 *ngIf="!database_populated" style="color: red;">No Photo's to show. Please go back and upload</h1>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

stage.component.ts

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    import { ImagingService } from '../../services/imaging.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-stage',
      templateUrl: './stage.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./stage.component.css']
    })
    export class StageComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private imageService: ImagingService) { }
    
      retrieveResponse: any;
      public namesList: any;
      imageName: string = "eating.jpg";
      base64Data: any;
      retrievedImage: any = null;
      currentImage = 0;
      public database_populated: boolean = false;
      totalImages: any;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.checkCount().then(count => {
          if (count > 0 ) {
            this.database_populated = true
            console.log("database is populated. going to cycle")
            this.cycle()
          }
          else {
            this.database_populated = false;
          }
        }) }


 cycle(){

    console.log("entering cycle")
    interval(10000).subscribe(x => 
    { 
      // update how many images there are in the database
      this.checkCount().then(data => {
        this.totalImages = data
      })
      console.log(this.totalImages)

      //update the list of image names found in the database
      this.updateNamesList().then(nameList => {
        this.namesList = nameList;
      })
      console.log(this.namesList)

      if (this.currentImage == this.totalImages){
        console.log("inside mod")
        this.currentImage = this.currentImage % this.totalImages
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("printing pictures")
        // display the Nth image in the list
        this.imageName = this.namesList[this.currentImage]
        // increment the image count in case there is another image added to the database
        this.currentImage = this.currentImage + 1
        this.getImage()
      }

    });
  }
    
    
      getImage() {
        //Make a call to Sprinf Boot to get the Image Bytes.
        this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/halloween/get/' + this.imageName)
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              this.retrieveResponse = res;
              this.base64Data = this.retrieveResponse.picByte;
              this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.base64Data;
            }
          );
      }
    
     async updateNamesList(){
        return await this.imageService.updateNamesList()
      }
    
     async checkCount(){
        return await this.imageService.checkCount()
      }
    }
```

imaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImagingService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public updateNamesList() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/halloween/allnames').toPromise();
  }

  public checkCount() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/halloween/check').toPromise();
  }

}
```

this is a snippet of the browser console errors and it shows the variables as undefined even though I place the promise prior to the console.log

[image: console error messages]

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work with asynch. Here is the order of execution.

```
      // command 1
      this.checkCount().then(data => {
        //command 3
        this.totalImages = data
      });
      // command 2, totalImages will be undefined.
      console.log(this.totalImages)
```

There is no guarantee about time at command 2, because we fetch data through network, so delay time may take few seconds.
You can await the result of checkCount to make sure we have data through rest api.:

```
this.totalImages = await this.checkCount();
```

Or you can do other things after rest api have an data.

```
      this.checkCount().then(data => {            
        this.totalImages = data
        doSomethingWithTotalImagesHere();            
      });
```